# Existence and uniqueness solution of $\dot{y}$ = $x^2 + y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show existence and uniqueness of the solution:
$\dot{y}$ = $x^2 + y^2$, where $|x| \le  1$, $|y| \le 1$ , $y(0)=0$.

Comment: Any thoughts or attempts?

Comment: It looks like a bit you could check the picard-lindelöf theorem

Comment: i know that its Picard–Lindelöf theorem, but i cant use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With Lipschitz-Lindelof:**

Well, if $\dot{y} = f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, then since $\left|x\right|, \left|y\right| \leq 1$, one can see that:

\begin{align*}
\left|f(x,y_2) - f(x,y_1)\right| &= \left| x^2 + y_2^2 - x^2 - y_1^2\right| \\ &= \left|y_2^2 - y_1^2\right|  \\ &= \left| (y_2-y_1)(y_2 + y_1) \right| \\ &\leq \left| y_2 + y_1 \right| \cdot \left| y_2 - y_1\right| \\ &\leq \left( \left| y_2 \right| + \left|y_1\right|\right) \cdot \left|y_2-y_1\right| \\ &\leq 2 \left|y_2-y_1\right|
\end{align*}

Thus, $f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous and this condition of the Picard-Lindelof Theorem holds. Then, for some $\varepsilon >0$, there will exist a solution to the initial value problem in some interval $\left[t_0 - \varepsilon, t_0 + \varepsilon\right]$ where $t_0 = 0$.

Then, since $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y$ is continuous, the solution will also be unique.

**Without the Theorem:** One can easily see that $y(t) =0$ is a solution for $x=0$ and the given IVP. Then by continuity of the partial derivative, the solution is unique.

Comment: how can i estimate the range of the solution's existence and uniqueness ? It's $[t_{0}$−ϵ,$t_{0}$+ϵ]
- so can i estimate ϵ or not ?

Answer (score 1):

The strong caracters underline the sufficient conditions to get existence and uniqueness (reduce case of Picard-Lindelöf).

---

Because you seek a solution on **the rectangle** $[-1,1]^2$ and $$f(x,y)\triangleq x^2+y^2$$ is **continous**. You have solution on some open interval in $[-1,1]^2$ that contains $0$.

---

Furthermore because $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ **is continous, the solution is unique**.

Comment: The function must be **Lipschitz**, not simply continuous.

Comment: Actually not https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Elementary_Differential_Equations_with_Boundary_Values_Problems_(Trench)/02%3A_First_Order_Equations/2.03%3A_Existence_and_Uniqueness_of_Solutions_of_Nonlinear_Equations

Comment: @Rebellos : $f$ is lipschitz (in $y$) in this case, as $\partial_y f$ is continuous. The theorem EDX is using is simply weaker then Picard-Lindelof (although it is quite similar)

Comment: @Caffeine absoluty.

Comment: @Caffeine I know, but "the theorem" reffers to Picard-Lindelof (most probably - since it was discussed in the comments), so as a statement is wrong.

Comment: I added some modifications to be clear.

Comment: how can i estimate the range of the solution's existence and uniqueness ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply Cauchy-Lipschitz Theorem, we have to check that $f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2$ is locally lipschitz with respect to $y$. Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ a bounded open interval and $(y,y’)\in I^2$.
Then, denoting $\sup I$ by $k/2$, we have

$$\| f(x_0, y) - f(x_0, y’)\| = \| (y-y’)(y+y’)\| \leq k \|y - y’\|.$$

Hence $f$ is locally lipschitz, and there is a unique solution satisfying $y(0)=0$. You can then restrict the domain of this solution in order to have $|x|, | y |\leq 1$ because $f$ is continuous.